# React: Having an error when I try to take components from my app and make new files from them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It reads:

"Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

I have seen other thread with about this particular issue with JS React but the solutions didn't work for me. I was making a shopping cart app with React and  it was working fine when everything was on one JSX page but when I start making files for every every compartment for example, "Products, "Cart".  . I am aware others have had this problem but I believe there are different ways you can get this error message.

Index.js:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
const PAGE_PRODUCTS = 'products'; 
const PAGE_CART = 'cart'; 

function App() {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(PAGE_PRODUCTS);
    

  const addToCart = (product) =>{ 
    console.log('we are in fart i mean cart');
    setCart([...cart, {...product}]);

  const removeFromCart = (productToRemove) =>{
    setCart(
      cart.filter(product => product !== productToRemove ));

  };

const navigateTo = (nextPage) => {setPage(nextPage);  
};


  



const renderCart = () => (
  <>
    <h1>Cart</h1>
    <div className="products">
    {cart.map ((product, idx) => ( 
      <div className="product" key={idx}>
      <h3>{product.name}</h3>
      <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
      <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}/>
      <button onClick = {() => removeFromCart(product)}>Remove</button>
      </div>     
    ))}
    </div>
    </>
); 


return (
    <div className="App">
    <header>
      <button onClick={() => navigateTo(PAGE_CART)}>Go to Cart ({cart.length})</button>
      <button onClick={() => navigateTo(PAGE_PRODUCTS)}>View Products </button>
    </header>
    {page === PAGE_PRODUCTS && (
    <Products addToCart={addToCart} />
    )}
    {page === PAGE_CART && renderCart()}
    
  </div>
  );

  };
}


  
  


 export default App;
```

Products.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 

    export default function Products({ addToCart }){
      const [products] = useState([
        {
          name: 'TWA FUCK 12 T-SHIRT',
          cost: '$19.99',
          image: 'https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/ba6f3a5b-075f-4fae-9efd-dd797e00931a/ddya15n-0c2ea56a-4735-470c-bee9-41dd09f9dfb9.png/v1/fill/w_250,h_250,strp/blue_lives_splatter_by_0r4lf1x4t10n_ddya15n-250t.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOiIsImlzcyI6InVybjphcHA6Iiwib2JqIjpbW3siaGVpZ2h0IjoiPD0xMjgwIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYmE2ZjNhNWItMDc1Zi00ZmFlLTllZmQtZGQ3OTdlMDA5MzFhXC9kZHlhMTVuLTBjMmVhNTZhLTQ3MzUtNDcwYy1iZWU5LTQxZGQwOWY5ZGZiOS5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9MTI4MCJ9XV0sImF1ZCI6WyJ1cm46c2VydmljZTppbWFnZS5vcGVyYXRpb25zIl19.bhFc4MR_BfROHMtp2C6Nl2GaQ1PeJS2piOioT3tyRgc'
  
        },
        {
          name: 'TWA THE WORLD IS YOURS T-SHIRT',
          cost: '$19.99',
          image: 'https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.974235379.7506/poster,504x498,f8f8f8-pad,600x600,f8f8f8.jpg'
  
        }
  
      ]);

      
        
        
       return ( 
       <>
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <div className="products">
        {products.map ((product, idx) => ( 
          <div className="product" key={idx}>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}/>
        <button onClick = {() => addToCart(product)}>Add To Cart</button>
          </div>     
        ))}
        </div>
        </>
        );
    }
```

Comment: your app doesnt return anything

Comment: The error message has stated it clearly, you didn't return anything from the App function.

Comment: ok if that is where it is, I will make a return function in app.js. Apologies, I am new to compartmentalizing React apps.